# Validation error when creating Lead lookup field in Activity object

Tags: standard-objects, activities

Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
"There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Lookups on activites must have a unique domain. You can not have multiple relationships to the same object."

I don't have any existing lookup field to the Lead object from the Activity object. So I'm not sure what's causing this error. I was able to create a Contact lookup field without issues, but when I create one for the Lead object, it spits out this error.

EDIT: I found the problem. I changed the UI to Classic, went to the Activity object's field and relationships page, and found the Deleted Fields link. In there, there was a lead lookup field. I deleted that and created a new lookup and everything was squared away.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two articles talking about Lookup Relationships on Activities in SFDC.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_sales_activities_activity_custom_lookups.htm

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrPdAAK

Both of them are slightly confusing, because they don't explain a main limitation very well.  You can only have 1 lookup relationship on Activities, so you are forced to make that one relationship work for your org.

From your question, it appears that you may be trying to make a lookup relationship for the Lead and for the Contact on the Activity object.  There is a field called WhoId that has the Id of the Contact, Lead, or User with limited Name object information.  It's not the same as a full lookup field, but it can be helpful.

Comment: `WhoId` is the right answer for this use case